# Unit testing a click in Angular12+ on Update button (testing method call on button click that navigates to a url)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a button click. The error I get is :Cannot match any routes. I am new to testing angular components, let ,me know if ,more info is required.

productComponent.html has code as:

```
<button id="addBtn" (click)="addButton()">ADD Product</button>
<table><tr>
<th> ID </th>
<th> ProductName </th></tr>
<tr *ngFor = 'let item in productList'>
<td> {{item.id}}</td> 
<td> {{item.Name}}</td>
<td> <button (click)="UpdateButton(item.id)"> View/Update</button> </td>
</tr></table>
```

productComponent.ts file has code as:

```
    addButton()
    {
       this.router.navigate(['AddProduct']);
    }
    UpdateButton(id: string)
    {
       this.router.navigate(['AddProduct',id]);   
    }
```

App-Routing.module.ts has routes as:

```
{ 
  path:'AddUpdateProduct',
  component: AddUpdateProduct
},
{
  path:'AddUpdateProduct/:id',
  component: AddUpdateProduct
}
```

The productComponent.Spec.ts

```
//test1
it('should call addButton on click of AddProduct', fakeAsync(() => {

spyon(component, 'addButton');

let button1 = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');

button1.click();

tick();

expect(component.addButton).toHaveBeenCalled();

}));

//test2
it('should call UpdateButton on click of Update Product', fakeAsync(() => 
let id:string='123abc';

spyon(component, 'UpdateButton');

button2.click();

expect(component.UpdateButton(id)).toHaveBeenCalled();

let button2 = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button'); tick();

}));

});
```

Test1 is passing, however test2 gives an error at console

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'AddUpdateProduct'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have two buttons and you don't differentiate in how they should be selected so for your 2nd test, it is still selecting the first button.

Try doing this:

```
// !! Add data-test attributes on the buttons
<button id="addBtn" data-test="add" (click)="addButton()">ADD Product</button>
<table><tr>
<th> ID </th>
<th> ProductName </th></tr>
<tr *ngFor = 'let item in productList'>
<td> {{item.id}}</td> 
<td> {{item.Name}}</td>
<td> <button data-test="update" (click)="UpdateButton(item.id)"> View/Update</button> </td>
</tr></table>
```

For the tests, select the button with the `data-test` attributes.

```
it('should call addButton on click of AddProduct', () => {

 // !! assign to a variable
 const addButtonSpy = spyOn(component, 'addButton');

 const button1 = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button[data-test="add"]');

 button1.click();


 expect(addButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});

it('should call UpdateButton on click of Update Product', () => 
  const id:string='123abc';

  const updateButtonSpy = spyOn(component, 'UpdateButton');
  
  cosnt button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button[data-test="update"]'); 

  button.click();

  expect(updateButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

Comment: it now gives Error: <toHaveBeenCalled>: Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: Ok, assign the spies to a variable and check that the variables were called. Check out my edit.

Comment: It is not throwing any error as of now. But the code `UpdateButton()
    {
       this.router.navigate(['AddProduct',id]);   
    }`  is not covered in the code coverage. Can it  be something to do with id parameter we are passing?

Comment: It is not being covered because that method is being spied on now so it is stubbed. It never goes inside of it.

Comment: ok, got it. So how do we check, if we want if that route was called on clicking the button? I tried the following code for that:

Comment: code: `it ('should navigate to UpdateButton url on click), ()  => { const location = TestBed.inject(Location) ; const Deblink = fixture.debugElement.queryAll (By.css(' button')) ;   const nativeElement: HTMLButtonElement = Deblink[1].nativeElement;                                                                                 nativeButton.Click(); fixture.detectChanges();                           fixture.whenStable().then( () =>{expect(location.path()).toBe('/UpdatePage/:id'); });`    I get the message "SPEC has no expectations' , though no error and it comes in code coverage

Comment: You get the error because it never goes inside of the `fixture.whenStable().then`. To check if the navigate was called, do `const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate')` beside the `updateButtonSpy` and then `expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();`.

Comment: It is giving error `Expected spy navigate to have been called`. I added a line of code in between" `component. UpdateButton (id)`. Something I am missing here?? Also I have updated the  .ts class to have `UpdateButton(id:string)` .

Comment: Oh right, change `const updateButtonSpy = spyOn(component, 'UpdateButton');` to `const updateButtonSpy = spyOn(component, 'UpdateButton').and.callThrough();` so the method is not stubbed and the actual implementation is called.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks. I wonder if this code I wrote earlier (where ,message was "SPEC has no expectations ") is of any use. By checking navigation we are already checking it all, right?

Comment: Yes, you don't need that variation.

Comment: Can you help me with this one as well? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73142422/how-to-unit-test-a-form-in-angular-using-jasmine-testing-framework)