# How to unit test a form in Angular using jasmine testing framework?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have code that initializes a form in a method. A private method is present in the code getProductById which needs to mocked in test and has been done. But then, form get loaded with those values, I am not able to check for initial values and the following test is failing.

I am new with angular testing and struggling in this part. The .ts file & test file is given below. The form is same for add and update We just update the form title and buttons accordingly.

```
export class InsertData implements OnInit (
isData = true;
ProductId? = null; 
loadForm = new FormGroup([
ProductName: new FormControl (''),
ProductDetails: new FormControl (''), 
id: new FormControl(),
});
title: String='';
submitted= false;

constructor(private router: Router,private productService: ProductService,
private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.loadAddForm Form();
this.productId - this.route.snapshot.params['id']; this.addData=!this.productId;

if (!this.addData){
this.title='Update';
this.getProducts(this.productsId!);}
else {
this.title="Add';

loadForm() {
 this.loadForm = this. formBuilder.group({
 ProductName:['',Validators.required],
 ProductDetails:['',Validators.required],
 id:[null]  });

 get f()
 {
 return this.loadForm.controls;
 }
  
 OnSave(){
 this.submitted=true;
 if(this.loadForm.invalid){
    return;
 }
 if(this.addData){
    this.productId =null;
    this.AddProductData(this.loadForm.value);
 }else{
    this.UpdateProductData(this.loadForm.value)
  };
 private AddProductData(ProductData: any){
  this.productService.addProdData(ProductData).subscribe({
  next: (response) => {
  alert('Data updated');
  this.router.navigateByURL('/ProductComponent'); 
 },
 error: (e) => console.error(e),
 complete: () => console.info('complete`),
 });}
```

The test method I have written so far is as below:

```
    beforeEach(async () = >{
      let mockproductService= jasmine.createSpyObj<ProductService>([
                             'getProductById'],['updateProduct']);
      const mockActivatedRoute ={snapshot: {params:['1'],},
      };
      
      //testing module configuration
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declaration:[InsertData],
       imports:[
               HttpCLientTestingModule, ReactiveModule,RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
    {
      path:'ProductListComponent',
      component: DummyComponent
    },
    providers:[{
      provide: ProductService,
      useValue: mockProductService}
    ],
    }}.compileComponents();
    
    mockProductService.getProductById.and.callFake(()=>{
    return of(mockgetProductById()); //method that returns some dummy values of name, description, id etc.
    
    fixture.TestBed.createComponent(InsertData);
    component= fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    });

//test method to test update 
it('should update on click of Update button',fakeAsync(()=>{
   const saveButtonSpy= spyOn(component,'OnSave').and.callThrough();
   const loadFormGroup = component.loadForm;
   
   //updating the values of fields
    loadFormGroup.patchvalue({
       'ProductDetails':"Testing Purpose"
     })
    component.OnSave();
    tick(100);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(saveButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    
    @Component({template:'/ProductListComponent})
    class DummyComponent{}
    
    function mockgetProductById(): ProductModel{
      mockProductModel ={
      id: '1',
      ProductName:'Cord',
      ProductDetails : 'Some description'
      } as ProductModel;
      return mockProductModel;
    }
```

`

Comment: Can you show your whole test suite and what you have done so far? This is a really good e-book with regards to Angular unit testing: https://testing-angular.com/. I encourage you to take your time and read it.

Comment: Thanks! I have written code for form validation already. A general code for field validation is done. Example  `it('ProductName should be ok when loaded first', () => { let pName= component.loadForm.controls[' productName']; expect (name.pristine).tobeTrue() ; name.SetValue('') ; expect.(name.errors).toBeTruthy() ;` . I am majorly struggling with the `it (should create)` . Like how to mock that method where loadAddForm() method is initialised in ngOnit.

Comment: If you want to mock `loadAddForm`, you can do `spyOn(component, 'loadAddForm');`. You should edit your question to paste what you have done for the test file.

Comment: I have updated the question with additional information and test done so far.

Comment: You can do `spyOn(component, 'loadAddForm').and.returnValue(...);` and then you can call `ngOnInit()` for the previous spy to take effect and then you can have your assertions.

Comment: @AliF50 yes it worked. This time I am testing the UpdateForm case on clicking the save button. I am updating the value using patchvalue for products details. This time error I am getting is : `cannot read the properties of undefined (reading subscribe)`. It is actually referring to a method that takes this data and returns observable response. How to mock it. I have added the test method for the same in the above code.

Comment: Do `productService.addProdData.and.returnValue(of(/* whatever value you require here */));` before the method is called.